# Jquery search div for text and put <b> around it

Tags: jquery, replace

In Twig I have a search form which searched in blog items, this all works fine but I want that the search query `{{ query }}` will be found and will be replaced by `<b>{{ query }}</b>` so my search results get a better look.

To accomplish this I tried the following:

```
$("body").html().replace(/{{ query }}/g, '<b>{{ query }}</b>'));
```

But I couldn't get this to work, nothing changes and I don't get an error message.

How can I use jQuery to select my search query and put `<b>` tags around them?

Comment: `But I couldn't get this to work.`

Any details ? console logs issue or your element is still the same ?

Comment: My element doesn't change, it doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it again. `.replace()` just returns the changed text.

```
$(function () {
  $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/{{ query }}/g, '<b>{{ query }}</b>'));
});
```

Also, remove the double `))`. Should be single. Also, I would suggest using wildcards replacement.

```js
$(function() {
  $("body").html($("body").html().replace(/\{\{ query \}\}/g, "<b>$&</b>"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<p>Hello {{ query }}</p>
<p>{{ query }} is great!</p>
```

Comment: it works, but I get the following error in my console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`

Comment: Something seems wrong with your answer, as I can't open that snippet.

Comment: @mike Same with me... It's not about the answer. It's about the CDNs. They are all down.

Answer (score 0):

Because you does not inserted replaced html into document. You need to insert new html into document.

```
$("body").html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/{{ query }}/g, '<b>{{ query }}</b>');
});
```

Or

```
$("body").html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/({{ query }})/g, '<b>$1</b>');
});
```

```js
$("body").html(function(i, h){
    return h.replace(/{{ query }}/g, '<b>{{ query }}</b>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>{{ query }}</div>
<p>{{ query }}</p>
```

Comment: Same here, it works but I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags`

Comment: @mike Use `.replace(/({{ query }})/g, '<b>$1</b>')` instead